# Accessing Rails RESTful routes in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To clean up my code I would like access to the RESTful helpers in my Rails model. Something like:

```
users_path
```

etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActionController::UrlWriter

 host = case ENV['RAILS_ENV']
 when "production"
   "yourlivedomain.com"
 when "development"
   "localhost:3000"
 end
 default_url_options[:host] = host
end
```

Answer (score 47):

Just to re-open this: For all rails 3+ users including UrlWriter won't work as it's deprecated.  What does work though, is this:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Hope that helps anyone who stumbled onto this like I did.

Comment: you don't need to include the helper; try `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path`

Comment: Do you really want to be writing all that every time you need a path in your module/class? Once off I guess it's acceptable but rather just do the include to access it from multiple places.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to access routes in your model? This is a violation of the Model/View/Controller (MVC) pattern that is at the heart of Rails. Models shouldn't have any knowledge of routes which are a controller and view concern. Models should stand alone from the user interface.

If you told us what you are trying to achieve then we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I'm sending a Twitter post after a new item is created on the web site. I want to use "after_create" to create the Tweet - hence I need a link back to the item.

Instead of a call in the controller which passes in the restful route, which is how I'm doing it now, I want to implement skinny controller - fat model.

Yes it only means removing a single line from a controller, but if it can be done ...

Comment: I think that in this case it's appropriate to do the work in the controller.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but I'd like to point out that there may be valid reasons to break Rails' patterns. I was looking for this answer because I'm adding a model whose only concern is to configure which part of the application to show just after login. There is a default configuration, some serialization logic to decide how to prioritize the module, then the page within the module, and although it can surely be done in a controller or a helper, I think it's much cleaner and self-contained in a model, which is a little easier to unit-test as well.